# Codeigniter views in main view

Tags: php, codeigniter-url

I'm loading views in a main view from controller with codeigniter like this

**Controller**

```
public function product_modules($domain_id)
{           
    $this->load->model('/admin/Model_products', '', TRUE);      
    $data['product_boxes'] = $this->Model_products->getProducBoxes($domain_id);
    $this->load->view('admin/dashboard',$data, null, true);

}
```

**Main View**

```
 $this->view($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```

but if the requested uri is containing query strings, the view is not getting loaded and I get a type `Unable to load the requested file: /admin/product_modules/1.php`. What would be the best workaround to call views dynamically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
    exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Example extends CI_Controller
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function _remap($method, $params = array())
    {
        // dynamically assign the method with parameters support
        $this->view($method, $params);
    }

    public function product_modules($domain_id)
    {
        $this->load->model('/admin/Model_products', '', TRUE);
        $data['product_boxes'] = $this->Model_products->getProducBoxes($domain_id);
        $this->load->view('admin/dashboard', $data, null, true);
    }

    public function view($method, $param1 = '', $param2 = '')
    {
        // params you can sent to models
        $data['users'] = $this->model_name->get_user($param1);

        // or views
        $data['myvar'] = $param2;

        // and load the view dynamically
        $this->load->view($method, $data);
    }

}
```

So

if the URL is `http://example/controller/method` then the above will search for `method.php` view file,

if URL is `http://example/controller/product_modules/1` then it search for `product_modules.php` view file.

Hope this helps. Thanks!!

Comment: @fefe, removed few lines that are not required.

Comment: thanks a lot on thing is not clear how to handle the view function can you give me another example

Comment: i show one example above. you can make conditional and extend further.